# Creating a Service in vs2019

Tags: c++, winapi

I wanted to create a service in VS2019, but it hasn't a template for it. So I created an empty project and then I try to write a service from ground up. I written the following main function.

```
#define SERVICE_NAME  _T("My Sample Service")

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Entry"));

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] =
    {
        {SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: StartServiceCtrlDispatcher returned error"));
        return GetLastError();
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Exit"));
    return 0;
}
```

But It says, you can't initialize a LPWSTR with a const wchar_t. This error is belong to the following line:

```
SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] =
        {
            {SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
            {NULL, NULL}
        };
```

But when I was watching video tutorial, the authro exactly written the above code but in vs 2019 I can't write such things. What should I do now?

Comment: use `const_cast<PWSTR>(SERVICE_NAME)` this not related to service or vs2019

Comment: @RbMm Can I define a non const string variable? if yes how?

Comment: Side note: I always worry about stuff like `(LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain` because the cast can hide an error in the `ServiceMain` prototype. What it is essentially saying is "Treat `ServiceMain` as though it is a `LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION` even if it isn't, and raise no errors or warnings if I'm about to shoot myself in the foot." Prefer to remove the cast and adjust `ServiceMain`  until you receive no errors or warnings.

Comment: for what you need not const string , when const is ok ? simply this is very old designed api which not care about different `PWSTR` and `PCWSTR`. must be `PCWSTR` in `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` by sense

Comment: @rbm This isn't about old vs. new. It's about C vs. C++. Assigning a string literal to a pointer to non-const is valid in C (and was valid in C++, up to C++11).

Comment: @IInspectable - in old code, old winapi definitions, frequently not accurate design functions parameters and structures. even if function/structure accept const/read only string - it declared anyway as PWSTR instead PCWSTR (ot PSTR instead PCSTR). despite i think in many case possible rewrite definitions. if in concrete case in `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` `LPWSTR lpServiceName` will be changed to `LPCWSTR                      lpServiceName` - this not break existing code and binary implementation. and not produce such error in modern c++

Comment: @RbMm, well, most of the  time it works, and in this case I believe too, but recall `CreateProcessW` function `lpCommandLine` parameter, that is non-constant for a reason that the function may modify the passed string in-place

Comment: @AlexGuteniev - yes, true in case `lpApplicationName == 0`. system need parse `lpCommandLine` and separate potential ApplicationName from parameters. `lpServiceName` another case, there is no need modify `lpServiceName`. of course all this implementation details, but extremally stable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW {
  LPWSTR                   lpServiceName;
  LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW lpServiceProc;
} SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW, *LPSERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW;
```

`LPWSTR` is `wchar_t*`. String literal `L"..."` can be assigned to `const wchar_t*` pointer, but not `wchar_t*` pointer.

Previously the Visual C++ compiler accepted such code. Now it will accept it with  `/permissive`, but will reject with `/permissive-`.

`/permissive` is the default option for the compiler, but `/permissive-` is set by default in Console Application project template. Generally, you shouldn't want to set `/permissive` for new code, it is more like an aid to port old code.

So, to fix compilation, you can:

- use `/permissive`
- cast away constness by `const_cast` or C-style cast
- use non-constant string, like `wchar_t ServiceName[] = L"My Sample Service";`

The last option is generally safest, as it makes no assumptions not defined by type system. However, the others are likely to be good enough, since this appears to be a widespread code sample for a service, and it is unlikely that it ever stops working.